# Create pseudo table cells to fill up table row

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table

I have a table which gets filled with content by a CMS. The amount of table data per row is different.
What I now get is something like this:
[image]

But what I want is something linke that:
[image]

Is there a way to accomplish that with HTML/CSS?
The unsexy way would be to count the table data in the longest row and then fill up the other rows with

Comment: Can you share your HTML and CSS on what you have done so far?

Comment: Share your code and we will be able to help you

Comment: Right now it's just a classic PHP loop through the content provided by the CMS.  Like this: https://codeshare.io/jGzQ9

Comment: To answer your question: Yes.

Comment: @RyanGibbs that's semi helpful. Can you provide a code example?

Comment: @Marco I wrote as much code as you did. :) Show us code or show us cash.

Comment: @RyanGibbs http://codeshare.io/jGzQ9